# C# .msi Installer Creation without <My Exe Name>.exe.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

When I create `.msi` file for `C# windows application`, the file `<myexename>.exe.config` automatically comes in the installation path after installing the .msi setup file.

How to exclude **.exe.config** file?

I think it is to be done during the Set up creation process itself.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<myexename>.exe.config` is a config file (`App.config`) of your application.
when you create installer for any windows application, it will autometically include it.
it is necessary, for example you stored your application database connection string in that or may be other settings also
 
so when you execute your application then your application `myexename` will look into `<myexename>.exe.config` for some settings as well for some necessary data required.

still, if you want to exclude it, perform the following steps: 
1)Right click on installer `project` -> `View` -> `File System` 
2)In `Application Folder`, Right Click on Primary Output of your application and select `Properties Window`
3)In Properties, Select `Exclude Files`
4)Click on `Add Filter` 
5)Enter `app.config` in text and press ok

now rebuild your project and install the .msi

`<myexename>.exe.config` will be removed from your installation directory